# Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" on running with javaagent

Tags: java, jar, instrumentation, bcel

I am trying to instrument a jar file (**main.jar**) with **javaagent.jar** using BCEL. basically where ever I find any aload in bytecode, I m trying to insert a function call to a  static function called Fun() in class "someclass" using

```
if (opcode instanceof aload) {
 iFactory.createInvoke("someclass", "fun", Type.VOID, new Type[]{}, Constants.INVOKESTATIC);
```

my "someclass" class reside in javaagent.jar

on executing

```
java  -javaagent:javaagent.jar -jar main.jar
```

or

```
java  -javaagent:javaagent.jar -jar main.jar javaagent.jar
```

or (I created a separate jar for my "someclass" called  **someclasscontained.jar**)

```
java -cp someclasscontained.jar  -javaagent:javaagent.jar -jar main.jar
```

I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: someclass
```

error. i tried with **-bootclasspath/p**  option but still not working. does anyone has any clue?

(1) all jar resides in  same folder 
2) this question may be similar to one question but solution is not correct/satisfactory for that question so please don't mark it duplicate )

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError mean that the ClassLoader couldn't find the class that it looks for. Most probably you are missing some dependencies. Did you tried the class name with full qualified name?

Comment: yes i tried with full qualified name like packagename.classname or packagename/classname  but its not working.

Comment: You may have case sensitivity problems

Comment: no bro , checked all silly mistakes

Answer (score 4):

If someclass is defined in a different jar file, you need to add it to the Boot-Class-Path list in your agent jar manifest file:

```
some.jar  -> contains someclass.class
javaagent.jar -> contains your instrumenting classes and MANIFEST.MF file

MANIFEST.MF file should contain line like
Boot-Class-Path: javaagent.jar some.jar
```